# StackOverFlow Error in Instantiating an Object

Tags: java, static, constructor, stack-overflow

I'm reviewing for a certification exam and I experimented with the following codes:

```
class A {   
    B b = new B();
    static {
        System.out.println("A static.");
    }
    {
        System.out.println("A instance.");
    }
    A() {
        System.out.println("A constructor.");
    }
}
class B extends A {
    static {
        System.out.println("B static.");
    }
    {
        System.out.println("B instance.");
    }
    B() {
        System.out.println("B constructor.");
    }
}

public class Raaawrrr {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A a = new A();
    }
}
```

It prints:

A static.
B static.

and causes a stack overflow afterwards. I'm having a hard time understanding why. Would you be able to help me out?

Comment: A class should not inheriit from a class that contains it. Makes no sense.

Comment: Definitely it makes no sense. But a lot of certification questions make no sense also, I'm just trying to understand some concepts here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A instantiates B. B happens to also be of type A, so that gets instantiated again. Which instantiates B... and so forth.

Answer (score 4):

You are creating an object of class `B` which is sub-class of `A` in class `A`. Note that the constructor of super-classes must *be* executed before the execution of sub-class constructor.